# having two struct reference each other - rust

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'm quite new to Rust programming, and I'm trying to convert a code that I had in js to Rust.

A plain concept of it is as below:

```
fn main() {
    let mut ds=DataSource::new();
    let mut pp =Processor::new(&mut ds);
}

struct DataSource {
    st2r: Option<&Processor>,
}

struct Processor {
    st1r: &DataSource,
}

impl DataSource {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        DataSource {
            st2r: None,
        }
    }
}

impl Processor {
    pub fn new(ds: &mut DataSource) -> Self {
        let pp = Processor {
            st1r: ds,
        };
        ds.st2r = Some(&pp);
        pp
    }
}
```

As you can see I have two main modules in my system that are inter-connected to each other and I need a reference of each in another.

Well, this code would complain about lifetimes and such stuff, of course . So I started throwing lifetime specifiers around like a madman and even after all that, it still complains that in "Processor::new" I can't return something that has been borrowed. Legit. But I can't find any solution around it! No matter how I try to handle the referencing of each other, it ends with this borrowing error.

So, can anyone point out a solution for this situation? Is my app's structure not valid in Rust and I should do it in another way? or there's a trick to this that my inexperienced mind can't find?

Thanks.

Comment: It's prohibited for good reasons. Moreover it seems off to me that `DataSource` really has to keep anything about `Processor`.

Comment: I would rather have `DataSource`'s methods to accept some `&Processor` as an argument. And if that's boilerplate, then `Processor` struct could have wrapper methods that call methods of `DataSource`, and passing `&self` as the argument

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct)

Comment: @kmdreko note that in the current question, both values are stored elsewhere (as local variables in `main`) and the question in only asking about mutual references.

Comment: Here's a quick solution: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=99f549167c973d069560ffe38f5276be)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do can't be expressed with references and lifetimes because:

- The `DataSource` must live longer than the `Processor` so that `pp.st1r` is guaranteed to be valid,
- and the `Processor` must live longer than the `DataSource` so that `ds.st2r` is guaranteed to be valid. You might think that since `ds.st2r` is an `Option` and since the `None` variant doesn't contain a reference this allows a `DataSource` with a `None` value in `st2r` to outlive any `Processor`s, but unfortunately the compiler can't know at compile-time whether `st2r` contains `Some` value, and therefore must assume it does.

Your problem is compounded by the fact that you need a *mutable* reference to the `DataSource` so that you can set its `st2r` field at a time when you also have an immutable outstanding reference inside the `Processor`, which Rust won't allow.

You can make your code work by switching to dynamic lifetime and mutability tracking using [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) (for dynamic lifetime tracking) and [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) (for dynamic mutability tracking):

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::{ Rc, Weak };

fn main() {
    let ds = Rc::new (RefCell::new (DataSource::new()));
    let pp = Processor::new (Rc::clone (&ds));
}

struct DataSource {
    st2r: Weak<Processor>,
}

struct Processor {
    st1r: Rc<RefCell<DataSource>>,
}

impl DataSource {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        DataSource {
            st2r: Weak::new(),
        }
    }
}

impl Processor {
    pub fn new(ds: Rc::<RefCell::<DataSource>>) -> Rc<Self> {
        let pp = Rc::new (Processor {
            st1r: ds,
        });
        pp.st1r.borrow_mut().st2r = Rc::downgrade (&pp);
        pp
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=99f549167c973d069560ffe38f5276be)

Note that I've replaced your `Option<&Processor>` with a `Weak<Processor>`. It would be possible to use an `Option<Rc<Processor>>` but this would risk leaking memory if you dropped all references to `DataSource` without setting `st2r` to `None` first. The `Weak<Processor>` behaves more or less like an `Option<Rc<Processor>>` that is set to `None` automatically when all other references are dropped, ensuring that memory will be freed properly.

Comment: Well I still cant understand completely whats happening here, but it solved my problem. A lot more to learn yet ....