# self-related borrowing error which I can't understand

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

MRE:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut framework = Framework {
        index_list: Vec::new(),
    };
    framework.method_one();
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Framework {
    index_list: Vec<usize>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Doc<'a> {
    framework: &'a Framework,
}

impl Framework {
    fn method_one(&mut self){
        println!("method one");
        let index_list: Vec<usize>;
        let (doc_map, index_list) = self.get_map_and_list();
        println!("map {:#?}, list {:#?}", doc_map, self.index_list);
        self.index_list = index_list;
        // uncommenting this causes the issue:
        // self.manipulate_list_more(doc_map);
    }
    
    fn get_map_and_list(&self) -> (HashMap<String, Doc>, Vec<usize>) {
        let mut doc_map = HashMap::new();
        doc_map.insert("bubble".to_string(), Doc{framework: &self});
        let mut index_list: Vec<usize> = Vec::new();
        index_list.push(99);
        (doc_map, index_list)
    }
    
    fn manipulate_list_more(&mut self, doc_map: HashMap<String, Doc>) {
        // NB whether this is "&self" or "&mut self" is irrelevant ...
        println!("submethod_two");
        // even if this is commented out we still get the error...
        // showing that the commands in this method are irrelevant to the problem involved
        // self.index_list.push(100);
    }
}
```

Naturally, this is a simplified version of what I'm doing. The `Doc` struct must have a reference to the `Framework` struct: hence the lifetime parameters. Ideally I would have liked to have both the map and the list as fields in the framework, but it gets very complicated if the framework has a field which refers back to `Doc` (as it would do in a `HashMap<String, Doc>`) (also `Framework` is a `pyclass`, which doesn't allow lifetimes!).

Now I'm having a problem with just manipulating the `Vec<usize>` field of the framework. If you uncomment `self.manipulate_list_more(...)` you will see the error:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `self.index_list` because it is borrowed
  --> src\main.rs:28:3
   |
26 |         let (doc_map, index_list) = self.get_map_and_list();
   |                                     ----------------------- `self.index_list` is borrowed here
27 |         println!("map {:#?}, list {:#?}", doc_map, self.index_list);
28 |         self.index_list = index_list;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `self.index_list` is assigned to here but it was already borrowed
29 |         self.manipulate_list_more(doc_map);
   |                                   ------- borrow later used here
```

... what I'm failing to understand is why a borrow doesn't start ... and then end. After the return from `self.get_map_and_list()`, hasn't `self` been borrowed and then **returned**? Seemingly not. But what would the problem with that be?

Secondly, with the problem line commented out, how come this problem doesn't arise? `self` was borrowed, and seemingly not returned, but the compiler then allows `self.index_list = index_list`: how come?

Is there a solution to what I'm trying to do?

Comment: The borrow doesn't end until it's last use. That is the `doc_map` which contains items of type `Doc<'a>` where `'a` is the lifetime of `&self` in  `get_map_and_list`

Comment: Thanks. But how come `self.index_list = index_list` is legal, **after** that borrow which has not ended? I'm surmising from your answer that the fact that `Doc` is "lifetimed" is a crucial element involved here: is that right?

Comment: What do you mean, the borrow ends at the last used place because of non lexical lifetimes.

Comment: `doc_map` contains a reference to `self`. of course it containing a reference to `self` constitutes a borrow.

Comment: Maybe this [version boiled down to the essentials](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=21b7d375833b5b30bd5142a5351b7bf7) clears it up.

Comment: Thanks for boiling it down to the essence. But I still don't understand why `self.index_list = index_list` is legal ... **until** you then add the line `self.manipulate_list_more(...)`.

Comment: @mikerodent because in the commented case, the borrow ends on the `println` line (the last time `doc_map` is used), so it is released before you change `self.index_list`. When you uncomment `self.manipulate_list_more (doc_map)`, then `doc_map` has to live long enough to be passed to `manipulate_list_more`, so `self` is still borrowed by `doc_map` when you try to change `self.index_list`.

Comment: @Jmb Thanks, that really explains the issue very clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with, partly inspired by Jmb's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70554377/595305). And after much struggling with the compiler.

As mentioned, I also really wanted the `HashMap` to be a field of `Framework`. That seemed impossible, but using an intermediate "holder" structure seems to do the job, as far as I can tell.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::fmt;

fn main() {
    let mut framework = Framework {
        index_list: Vec::new(),
        holder: Rc::new(RefCell::new(Holder{doc_map: HashMap::new()})),
    };
    framework.method_one();
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Framework<'a> {
    index_list: Vec<usize>,
    holder: Rc<RefCell<Holder<'a>>>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Holder<'a> {
    doc_map: HashMap<String, Doc<'a>>,
}

// necessary to implement this: otherwise you get stack overflow 
// on "{:#?}" because of all the self-referencing structures
impl fmt::Display for Holder<'_> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        let mut s  = "hashmap keys:\n".to_string();
        for (key, value) in self.doc_map.clone().into_iter() {
            s.push_str(&format!("key {}\n", &key));
            
        };
        write!(f, "{}", s)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Doc<'a>{
    holder: Rc<RefCell<Holder<'a>>>,
}

impl Framework<'_> {
    fn method_one(&mut self){
        self.populate_map_and_list();
        println!("--- self.index_list {:?}\n", self.index_list);
        println!("--- self.holder {}\n", *self.holder.borrow());
        self.manipulate_more();
        println!("--- self.index_list {:?}\n", self.index_list);
        println!("--- self.holder {}\n", *self.holder.borrow());
    }
    
    fn populate_map_and_list(&mut self) {
        let rc_ptr = &self.holder;
        let doc:Doc = Doc {holder: (*rc_ptr).clone().into()} ;
        self.holder.borrow_mut().doc_map.insert("bubble".to_string(), doc);
        self.index_list.push(99);
    }
    
    fn manipulate_more(&mut self) {
        let rc_ptr = &self.holder;
        let doc:Doc = Doc {holder: (*rc_ptr).clone().into()} ;
        self.holder.borrow_mut().doc_map.insert("jubble".to_string(), doc);
        self.index_list.push(100);
    }
}
```

Obviously this doesn't enable you to reach `Framework` from `Doc`. So anything which `Doc`s need to reference must be kept in the `Holder` `struct`. Or ... there may be some way that `Holder` can supply some kind of reference to `Framework`. I have my doubts about that though.

A thread-safe version also works using `Arc` and `Mutex`. That naturally tends to pose a few locking-related challenges.